# redirect (mt) media temple domain to godaddy server?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, godaddy, mediatemple

okay, i bought a mediatemple domain because its cheaper than godaddy. but i have a godaddy server and i was wondering what i have to do to the DNS records to get the domain i bought from (mt) to redirect to my current goDaddy server. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this depends on how your setup at GoDaddy, you have 2 options really

change the nameservers to the correct ones that are linked with your server over there

or simply use (mt)'s dns control panel to set the appropriate A records for your domain to the IP of your GoDaddy server

Comment: I'm actually just going to transfer the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Anthony's answer is spot on. If you need help with it, you can also take a look at our wiki for more information on it.

http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28mt%29:Edit_DNS_zone_file_records